# How do I create a negated matrix? (Python)

Tags: python, list, matrix, negate

Let's say I have a matrix `[[-2,4],[-6,8]]`.

I want to know how to get the opposite of those numbers: `[[2,-4],[6,-8]]`.

Is there a special function in Python I'm supposed to use?

Comment: If you're doing linear algebra in Python, use numpy.

Answer (score 3):

numpy is awesome :P

```
a = numpy.array( [[-2,4],[-6,8]])
a *= -1
print a
```

Comment: why not simply `a = -a` ?

Comment: Is there a way to do it Without numpy? I'd prefer not using packages.

Comment: @shaktimaan's answer covers doing it without numpy ... but really numpy is an amazing package

Comment: You can just do: `a = -numpy.array( [[-2,4],[-6,8]])`

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension is one way to go about it:

```
>>> data = [[-2,4],[-6,8]]
>>> [[-ele for ele in item] for item in data]
[[2, -4], [6, -8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy

matrix = numpy.array([[-2,4],[-6,8]])
negatedMatrix = matrix * -1

print negatedMatrix
```

Giving the output:

```
[[ 2 -4]
 [ 6 -8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to import packages and you also have a problem with list comprehensions but you like unnecessary complicated things you can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and `lambda` like this:

```
data = [[-2,4],[-6,8]]
reversed_data = map(lambda sublist: map(lambda x: -x, sublist), data)
# [[2, -4], [6, -8]]
```

EDIT: This example is working in python 2.7. In python 3+ `map()` returns an iterator so you need to do `list(map())` to get this result. (credit goes to SethMMorton)

Comment: Note that in python3 `map` returns a *map object*, so you'd have to do  `list(map())` to get this result in that case.